# I Cant load parent component data into form field as a uneditable value. Can anyone guide

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form to display where only one input box must be pre filled with values that come from a parent component. The input box must also be made un-editable. Here is the code for the HTML and the TS file for the same being defined in a very crude form form.

**triggerform.component.html:**

```
{{triggerID}}<!-- shows the fetched value -->
<form #userForm="ngForm">
<input type="text" name="triggerID" [(ngModel)]="userData.triggerID"><br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
```

**triggerform.component.ts:**

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-triggerform',
  templateUrl: './triggerform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./triggerform.component.css'],
})
export class TriggerformComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parentEmailID!: string;
  @Input() triggerID!: any;
  @Input() triggerAssignedTo!: string;
  @Input() isActive!: boolean;
  userData={
    triggerID: this.triggerID
  }
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

But still my input box appears empty.Can anyone please help in getting this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook for that. This method will be triggered everytime your Input() decorator receives a value from the parent. You will have something like:

```
export class TriggerformComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
    @Input() triggerID!: any;

    userData = {
        triggerID: '',
    };

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.userData.triggerID = this.triggerID;
    }
}
```

Although since you have more than one input, this will be triggered every time any of yours Input() receives a value and that's not good. So you can use a set method for that, something like:

```
export class TriggerformComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() set triggerID(id: any) {
        this.userData.triggerID = id;
    }

    userData = {
        triggerID: '',
    };
}
```

The triggerID inside userData will be initialized only when the triggerID Input() receives a value and updated every time a new value is passed from the parent to the child.

I'm not sure if I understood the uneditable value part, if you mean like a disabled input, you can just add the disabled attribute in your input tag

```
<input type="text" name="triggerID" [(ngModel)]="userData.triggerID" disabled><br><br>
```